# Laravel: Return the updated model with additional pivot data

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am successfully updating the data in my pivot table. I am now trying to return the updated model - including the pivot data that was just updated.

I am able to return the model, but not sure how to get to the pivot data from there.

Here is my controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, Role $role)
    $user->roles()->updateExistingPivot($attributes['id'], $attributes); // 200 status

    ...

    return response()->json(['role' => $role], 200); 

    // have also tried this - and does return the value, but would like the whole object if possible.
    $active = $user->roles->find($attributes['id'])->pivot->active;
}
```

Here is my `User` model:

```
public function roles(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_user', 'user_id')
        ->withPivot('active') // this is the column I am updating
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Everything above is working. My data is getting updated as are the timestamps in my pivot table.

The problem I (think) I am getting is that i'm returning the same `$role` that was passed in. I am using a vue component to render the results, so I'd like to use the actual data that comes back from my database.

Even if I look up the `Role` using a query, I am just getting the model back; not including the pivot column(s) I would like to read.

I am checking the response in my vue component like this:

```
console.log('response.data', response.data);

response.data {
    role:
        created_at: "..."
        title: "foo"
        ...
}
```

The above renders the same model object (without the pivot column). How can I attach my `active` pivot column to the response data? Thank you for your suggestions!

**SOLUTION**

Thank you matticustard for your help. That was exactly the nudge I needed to get pointed in the right direction. Here's what my code looks like in hopes it'll help someone else.

**controller**

```
$public function update(Request $request, Role $role)
{
    $attributes = request()->validate([
        'active' => 'required',
        'id' => 'required',
    ]);

    $user = auth()->user();

    $user->roles()->updateExistingPivot($attributes['id'], $attributes);

    // Return the role using the relationship.
    $role_with_pivot = $user->roles()->where('role_id', $attributes['id'])->first();

    return response()->json(['role' => $role_with_pivot], 200);
}
```

The above will return this as a response after updating my database:

```
role:
    created_at: "..."
    icon: "..."
    id: 1
    pivot:
        active: true
        role_id: 1
        user_id: 1
        ...
    title: "foo"
    ...
```

**vue component**

```
<template>
    <div class="role" :class="{'active': active}" @click="handleClick($event, role)">
        <div v-if="role.icon" class="role-icon">
            <i :class="role.icon"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="role-title">
            {{ role.title }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

...


data() {
    return {
        active: this.role.pivot.active,
    }
},

...

methods: {
        async handleClick(event, role) {
            try {
                let response = await axios.patch(`/my-path/${role.id}`, {
                    active: !this.active,
                    id: role.id,
                });

                if (response.status === 200) {
                    console.log('response.data', response.data);
                    this.active = response.data.role.pivot.active;
                    console.log('active: ', this.active);
                } else {
                    console.error('Error: could not update role. ', response);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error: sending patch request. ', error);
            }
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pivot data is only loaded when a corresponding relationship is loaded.  Otherwise, there is no query performed to touch the pivot table.  With default [# Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#route-model-binding), only the model is retrieved.

You will need to explicitly perform a relationship driven lookup.

```php
// load the role using the relationship
$role_with_pivot = $user->roles()->where('id', $role->id)->first();

// in some circumstances, it may be necessary to use the full table name
// $role_with_pivot = $user->roles()->where('roles.id', $role->id)->first();

return response()->json(['role' => $role_with_pivot], 200);
```

You should then be able to access the pivot data in your response.

```js
let active = response.data.role.pivot.active;
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly the nudge I needed. I updated my question with what I ended up doing in hopes it'll help someone else. Thank you very much!